# Why Hyper v 2012 server does not show up MMC option

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012, windows, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have remotely logged on to a Hyper V 2012 server which is in domain from a windows 2012 server through remote desktop connection and after login the first thing which was configured to run automatically when you log into a Hyper-V server was the SConfig.cmd and in the same I followed the below mentioned steps to as per this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/11/11/configuring-remote-management-of-hyper-v-server-in-a-workgroup.aspx as reference.

Step 1: Select option 4 on the SConfig menu (labeled Configure Remote Management)

But did not find the "Allow MMC Remote Management" option mentioned in the step 2 below.

Step 2: Then select options 1 (Allow MMC Remote Management) and 2 (Enable Windows PowerShell).

Request to post for solutions in detail as I am new to server maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The article you are quoting is about Hyper-V Server 2008 R2, you are using 2012.

In the 2012 version there is no option `Allow MMC Remote Management`, use: `1) Enable Remote Management`